# What is the proper way to get the real recorded date/time of a video stream?

Tags: timestamp, video-streaming, directshow, playback

I have a complete `video-streaming` mechanism of my own at the moment (except GDCL Mux/Demux filters). Structure is like this.

Streamer Graph:

```
File Source Filter -> GDCL MP4 Demuxer -> My RTP Network Renderer
```

Receiver Graph:

```
My RTP Network Listener -> GDCL MP4 Muxer -> My Video Renderer
```

I don't use `RTSP` protocol and pass required startup parameters by some custom methods. I stream segmented files continuously. To do that, i create a new `Streamer Graph` for the next file each time end of file is reached. But keep using the same `UDP` port at the next `Streamer Graph`. So,  `My RTP Network Listener` keeps listening and continues to stream as soon as the new `Streamer Graph` is built and started running.

I don't use another communication method like `RTCP` at the moment. Audio streaming is incomplete, so I don't have audio-video syncing problems (yet!).

**Here comes the important part**

All I want is to get **the real recorded date/time** information from the stream. MP4 filenames are in date/time format. So, I know when exactly the file recording has started. I know I can calculate the recording date/time using:

```
Recording Start Date/Time Value + Media TimeStamp Value Of The Stream
```

But what if there is a gap between two recorded files? When I build a new `Streamer Graph`, timestamps will start counting from zero again, right?

**Here comes the question**

So, what is the proper way to handle this kind of situations? I know `RTCP` is being used for audio-video syncing. Can it also be used for my case as well? Or do I need to use a second `UDP` port (just like `RTCP`) and send some custom date/time information messages?

I can think of more than one solution to fix my problem. But if there is a usual and more proper way, I don't want to use an ugly solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an additional UDP port to send date/time information (4 bytes unix timestamp). It works fine, my player counts the timer correctly and all date/time information is received with the video stream at the same time. I still think there should be a better, industry standard way but since no one has decided to answer my question, I wanted to share my own solution.

```
Port Offset   : RTP Video Stream
Port Offset+1 : Date/Time Information (Unix TimeStamp)
```

Calculation of unix timestamp (seconds):

```
File Recording Start DataTime + Seek Time + (Media TimeStamp / 100000)
```

Hope 1: It helps someone with a similar case in the future.

Hope 2: Someone answers this question advicing a better method.